# Resend failed messages with Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch

Tags: serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

I'm using the Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch nuget package and Elasticsearch was missing shards for a while. As a result I've got a lot of failed messages saved as invalid-**.json files.
How do I resend those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. Install Elasticsearch.Net nuget package

```
    private static async Task RetryLogMessages(string url, string directory)
    {
        string doneDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(directory, "Done");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(doneDirectoryPath);
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "invalid*.json");
        ElasticLowLevelClient client = new(new ConnectionConfiguration(new Uri(url)));
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string[] json = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);

            DynamicResponse response = await client.BulkAsync<DynamicResponse>(PostData.MultiJson(json));
            await Task.Delay(100);// Take it easy??

            if (response.Success)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                string destFileName = Path.Combine(doneDirectoryPath, fileName);
                File.Move(filePath, destFileName);
                Console.WriteLine($"{fileName} done");
                // File.Delete(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.HttpStatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine(response.OriginalException);
            }
        }
    }
```